# How can I prevent Latex from doing something "bad" to my computer?

Tags: miktex, windows, security

More precisely, I want to run PDFLatex on a server and let it accept arbitrary .tex source files from users, returning the compiled pdf to them. However, obviously this introduces a security threat (most importantly in terms of write access to the server's file system).

I have read this very similar question where the answers hint at performing some changes to `texmf.cnf`: [How can I safely compile other people's LaTeX documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10418/how-can-i-safely-compile-other-peoples-latex-documents)

But first of all, I am using Miktex (2.9), and it doesn't seem to use a `texmf.cnf` config file. Where would I perform the described changes in Miktex?

And second of all, I am running a Windows server. Is there anything special to consider in this case?

I am aware that this is a quite open-ended question, and I'm not looking for a definitive answer. I'd just like to avoid the most obvoious risks. So any "creative" ideas (from a hacker's point of view) will be appreciated!

Comment: Don't enable `\write18` macros... or `\pdfshellescape`, etc.  In MikTeX, these should be disabled by default, unless you enable them.

Comment: See this discussion: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262625/3929

Comment: Okay, so in essence I don't have to worry as long as I don't touch the default settings?